# subset rows of pandas dataframe by string match on column

Tags: python, pandas

pool is a dataframe, and one of the columns is "Name"
If key == 'Bob', then this line correctly gives me all the rows where Name=='Bob':

```
keyrows = pool[key == pool.Name]
```

I instead want to get all the rows that match 'Bob', like "Bob Jones" and "Bob Marley", etc.

So I changed '==' to 'in', but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
keyrows = pool[key in pool.Name]
```

I get
KeyError: False

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use [`.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) or [`.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match). see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) for examples

Answer (score 6):

@behzad.nouri gave me the solution:

```
keyrows = pool[pool.Name.str.contains(key)]
```

does exactly what I want.